# How to set default value of DateTimePicker to display some non-date string such as "MM-DD-YYYY"

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I am using VB.NET's `DateTimePicker`, but, when it is first created, it always shows the current date by default (e.g. 01-09-2015).  I want to change it so it defaults to some literal string like "MM-DD-YYYY" rather than the current date.

Comment: Could you show us some code ?

Comment: This isn't in fact a duplicate, the question is how to show the literal string MM-DD-YYYY in the DateTimePicker (which I don't think is possible anyway)

Comment: The `DateTimePicker` always contains a valid date value.  It is the reason it exists.  As such it cant display anything but Dates.

Comment: The control is called a DateTimePicker because it's meant to display dates and times. `MM-DD-YYYY` is not a date or time value in any calendar or time system I've ever seen, and I doubt MS has either.

Comment: Stuff like "MM-DD-YYYY" is usually used to prompt users that a Date  input is required.  If your users look at a DTP and dont know a date is required, you need smarter users.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom format for this.

Set the Format property to Custom and then set the CustomFormat property to 'MM-DD-YYYY' (be sure to include the ' characters).

You will probably need to reset the format once the user selects a date so that the selected date is displayed properly.  You can do this in the ValueChanged event handler:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Long
End Sub
```